# App Crashes when I try to switch view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm rather new to Objective-C and I have an issues which I can't seem to fix!
When I launch my application I have 4 buttons! Each of these buttons should redirect to another XIB file (and ofc each of these XIB files will have a button to go back)

However when I try to push 1 of the buttons my application "crashes"!
**This is what the console shows me:**

```
[Session started at 2011-03-07 14:15:38 +0100.]
2011-03-07 14:15:42.169 Google Calendar[1332:207] -[UIApplication gettingStarted:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c17fa0
2011-03-07 14:15:42.173 Google Calendar[1332:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UIApplication gettingStarted:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c17fa0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0124bbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x013a05c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x0124d6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
     3   CoreFoundation                      0x011bd366 ___forwarding___ + 966
     4   CoreFoundation                      0x011bcf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
     5   UIKit                               0x00502a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
     6   UIKit                               0x005911b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
     7   UIKit                               0x00593647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
     8   UIKit                               0x005921f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
     9   UIKit                               0x005270d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
     10  UIKit                               0x0050837a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
     11  UIKit                               0x0050d732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
     12  GraphicsServices                    0x01968a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
     13  CoreFoundation                      0x0122d064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
     14  CoreFoundation                      0x0118d6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
     15  CoreFoundation                      0x0118a983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
     16  CoreFoundation                      0x0118a240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
     17  CoreFoundation                      0x0118a161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
     18  GraphicsServices                    0x01967268 GSEventRunModal + 217
     19  GraphicsServices                    0x0196732d GSEventRun + 115
     20  UIKit                               0x0051142e UIApplicationMain + 1160
     21  Google Calendar                     0x00002304 main + 102
     22  Google Calendar                     0x00002295 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

And here is what I'm try to do:
**h-file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

}
-(IBAction)gettingStarted:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)appointments:(id)sender;

@end
```

**m-file**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "AppointmentViewController.h"
#import "GettingStartedViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

-(IBAction)gettingStarted:(id)sender {
     GettingStartedViewController *gettingStartedVC = [[GettingStartedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self presentModalViewController:gettingStartedVC animated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)appointments:(id)sender {
     AppointmentViewController *appointmentVC = [[AppointmentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self presentModalViewController:appointmentVC animated:YES];
}
-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

P.S.: Both viewControllers (GettingStartedViewController & AppointmentViewController) are created!

If you guys need more code (just leave a comment)

Thx

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

It seems `gettingStarted:` message is sent to the UIApplication object, not the FirstViewController object. Make sure everything is correct (File's Owner etc.) when you make a connection in IB.

---

The typical pattern here using Nib is to create the FirstViewController using Nib. Your FirstView_iPhone.xib will have a viewcontroller object, of which class name is set to FirstViewController. Then when the Nib is loaded, the FirstViewController object will be created. Also you can use its methods as actions from IB.

Technically you could add an external object to FirstView_iPhone.xib and set its class to FirstViewController and use it to make target-action connections.

Alternatively, if you want to create the view controller object programmatically, you could add target-action connections programmatically as well (using `setTarget:action:` method).

Comment: my 'main' xib is FirstView_iPhone.xib in this xib are the 4 buttons, so gettingStarted: is sent (or should be at least) to GettingStartedViewController object. I just checked the gettingstarted.xib and the File's Owner is correctly linked with the GettingStartedViewController object

Comment: What matters is the target-action connection from the buttons on the main view, thus File's Owner of gettingstarted.xib is not relevant. The problem should be in FirstView_iPhone.xib, and its File's Owner should probably be the UIApplication. I wonder how it's possible to connect action to UIApplication if it does not declare gettingStarted:, so I'm not 100% sure, but the target of the action must be the FirstViewController object, not the UIApplication object.

Comment: I gave the File's Owner of FirstView_iPhone.xib the value FirstViewController because else I couldn't reach my 2 functions (gettingStarted: and appointments:) Anyhow I changed it back to UIApplication and via First Responder in IB I was able to reach my 2 functions again. Now when I launch my app and click something they dont do anything! So I wrote a little text that should be visible in the console, but that doesn't appear either. (Thanks for the help so far ;))

Comment: Don't change File's Owner and First Responder of FirstView_iPhone.xib in this case. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the `gettingStarted:` message is being sent to the wrong object. The printed console output shows the message is being sent to UIApplication. Make sure you have your actions hooked up in IB correctly. Control-drag from the button you want to fire the action to the FirstViewController object in your IB document and select `gettingStarted:`. Then, add `NSLog` statements to your method implementations to see if they're getting invoked.